# Define an End-Date for repeated Local Notification

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on a simple application that sets some `NSLocalNotification` with a repeat interval.

I'm stuck in a strange situation :

- If my user don't open the app, how can I stop these notification ?
- Is there a way to define and **end-date** other than the `fireDate` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing a set interval you could get around this by just setting individual notifications for the intervals up to the date that you want it to stop. When they user reopens the app you can just clear those out and reset them. This may or may not be too a lot but this is actually something I have done myself.